# What condition should an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ meet for $x\mapsto\|Ax\|$ to define a vector norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

What condition should an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ meet for the function $x\mapsto\|Ax\|$ to define a vector norm. where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes some vector norm in $\mathbb R^m$?

Should $A$ have full rank? Because if $A$ does not have full rank then the first property of matrix norm is violated. That is my solution. Is it right?

Answer (score 1):

Property 1. and 2. in the definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Definition are always satisfied. Property 3. is satisfied if and only if $Av=0$ implies $v=0$ which is equivalent to say that $m\le n$ and $A$ has full rank.

Comment: Usually "full rank" means that $\operatorname{rank}(A) = \min(m, n)$, but this isn't sufficient in this case. You also need the condition $m \le n$. Equivalently, you can demand $A$ to have trivial kernel.

Comment: right, corrected!